# STFT Audio processing with zeros

Tags: fft, python, stft, feature-extraction, librosa

In [this paper](http://www.cp.jku.at/people/schedl/Research/Publications/pdf/MIREX_SSPK2_2010.pdf) they preprocess an audio file with a STFT and then apply two equations to the computed matrix.

[image]

[image]

I tried implementing all of it in python and used librosa for the STFT.
The issue I encountered is, that the matrix includes a lot of low values or zeros.
By the 2. equations including `log` those values get transformed to `nan` latest in the second step. As soon as there are `nan`s involved all future aggregations I want to compute doesn't work.

Here is an example of the magnitude spectrum, cent spectrum(EQ1) and cent scale(EQ2):
[image]

What is the best way to solve such a problem? Do I have to transform the matrix I get from librosa further?

Comment: Add a very small value to $X[k]$ before taking the $\log$. Something like $1e^{-8}$

Comment: @Jdip I'm wondering, is this a common problem?

Answer (score 1):

The equation isn't entirely correct. Normally you would define the level as

$$L[k] = 20 \cdot \log_{10}\frac{|X[k]|}{X_{ref}}$$

where $X_{ref}$ is a suitable reference. Could be 1V (for dBV) 20$\mu$ Pa (for dBSPL), 1mW (for dBm), etc. Which reference to use depends on your application your setup and what information is available.

This definition can become a problem when $X[k] = 0$. In this case the level is $-\infty$ (not, NaN which is just a programming artifact). Whether this is a problem or not depends on what you want to do with the data.

If you don't want to deal with $-\infty$ you define the maximum dynamic range and add a small offset to your data. For example, if you want to limit your range to, say, 100dB you can do something like

$$L[k] = 20 \cdot \log_{10}\frac{|X[k]|+10^{5}\cdot \max\{|X[k]|\}}{X_{ref}}$$

> I'm wondering, is this a common problem

Yes. Not so much with real physical data as this rarely contains values that are exactly zero but if often happens with mathematical models. A simple example is a first order highpass filter which has a gain of 0 at 0Hz (i.e. $X[0] = 0$)

Comment: I want to implement the whole algorithmn of that paper.
Basically it converts the cent scale into 6 different vectors which right now mostly consists of `nan`s.
My knowledge in signal processing is limited so I'm not sure if that is what the authors intended.

Comment: The main question I have is:
Is it normal for a fft to output very small values?

Comment: @Rocket: It really depends on the nature of your signals,.  For some class of signals its normal, for other's it isn't.